# For Text, Appending is not happening in word doc (.docx) in Java Code

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have tried using below code to append the content present in word doc:

```
    XWPFDocument doc=new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFParagraph para=doc.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun run=para.createRun();
    File f=new File("Text.docx");
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f, true);
    run.setText("Append The value please");
    doc.write(fos);
```

But, after completion of program, when I try to open the file, it says "**We're sorry. We can't open the file. We found a problem with its content**" .

I am using below jars:
1.  Poi 3.12
2.  Poi -ooxml-3.10.1
3.  Poi-scratchpad-3.15
4.  Ooxml-schemas-1.1
5.  Xmlbeans-2.3.0
6.  Dom4j-1.1

what is the reason of this & what could be the solution to avoid this?

Comment: Maybe because you forgot to close the document. doc.close() after write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because, you are not opening the file using Apache POI.

Use XWPFDocument to open the word document to append data. Pfb the code.

```
 XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fileLocationPath + "Document.doc"));


    List<XWPFParagraph>  paragraphs = doc.getParagraphs();


    XWPFParagraph paragraph =  paragraphs.get(paragraphs.size() - 1);

    XWPFRun runText = paragraph.createRun();

//if you want to add text
    runText.setText("appending here");

//if you want to add image
    runText.addPicture(java.io.InputStream pictureData, int pictureType, java.lang.String filename, int width, int height)



    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileLocationPath + "Document.doc")) {
            doc.write(out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

if you want to add image - use addPicture Method of XWPFRun - refer here - [Apache POI XWPFRun Add Picture](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#addPicture%28java.io.InputStream,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: `doc.commit();` - > `error: commit() has protected access in XWPFDocument`

Comment: @AxelRichter, Thanks for noting, I have edited it to save using fileoutputstream.

Comment: Thank you. It's working for text but I am getting same error while I try to append any image. Although, size of new file is increased. Can you please give your input?

Comment: @Rohit Kumar, Your question is about adding text, so I added code based on that.

Comment: @Rohit Kumar, I have edited the answer for you - for adding image as well. Please mark as answered if it answers your qery - a tick mark to the left of answer,

Comment: In normal document, I am able to append. But if a document is already having some content with header & footer then i face the problem. 
Note: I would like to paste the picture in between the header & footer. For text, it's happening @Srikanth A.

Comment: I used all the poi jars of 3.15 version & it worked.